# Show a Twitter timeline on Ionic Framework

Tags: twitter, ionic-framework

I've trying (for a week) to find a way to show a twitter timeline in a Ionic App tab but I can't.
I don't want to login on Twitter, I just want to show a user timeline.
I can do it easily in Html5 but it looks no so easy in Ionic.

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

To access to the Twitter API, it is necessary to implement the Oauth authentication.
You can easily use the ngCordova plugin : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I can't understand why I can show a user timeline (with the twitter widget) in a html5 document and I need Oauth in Ionic.